# Parsing a complex XML string (RXML)

Tags: xml, xcode, parsing

This is my simplified XML string:

```
<rss>
 <channel>
  <item>
   <title>ITEM TITLE</title>
   <description>
    &lt;i&gt;Att1 &lt;/i&gt;10, &lt;i&gt;Att2 &lt;/i&gt;20, &lt;i&gt;Att3 &lt;/i&gt;30
   </description>
  </item>
  <item>
  ...
  </item>
  ...
 </channel>
</rss>
```

With this RXML code I can parse the ENTIRE < description> tag:

```
RXMLElement *rxmlRoot = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_XML_URL]];
    RXMLElement *firstLevel = [rxmlRoot child:@"channel"];
    NSArray *secondLevel = [firstLevel children:@"item"];
    [rxmlRoot iterateElements:secondLevel usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *appElement) {
        NSString *description = [appElement child:@"description"].text;
```

And its perfect! The parsed *description string is: "< i>Att1< /i> 10, < i>Att2< /i> 20, < i>Att3< /i> 30"

But I want to parse the separate values of Att1, Att2 and Att3; I need to extrapolate the single value of 10, 20 and 30, unluckly in the same tag. Its possible? There is a way to do it with RXML, or another xml parser for XCode? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have in the past run a regex on the result to get rid of this.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"< i>Att[0-9]< /i>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:nil];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:description
                      options:0
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, description.length)
                 withTemplate:@""];
```

There are also libraries that can strip html tags if your data is not in the same format.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I have other little issues, but certainly this is a good starting point to parse similar data!